# What is the reason for list.__str__ using __repr__ of its elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the reason for `list.__str__` using `__repr__` of its elements?

Example:

```python
class Unit:
    def __str__(self):  return "unit"
    def __repr__(self): return f"<unit id={id(self)}>"

>>> str(Unit())
'unit'

>>> str([Unit()])
'[<unit id=1491139133008>]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lists used the `str()` of their elements rather than their `repr()`, then what would an output of `[1, 2]` mean?  Is that a list with two integers, two strings, or one of each?  Or is it a list with *one* element, the string `"1, 2"`?  Python made the only choice that allows you to determine *anything at all* about the contents of a list by looking at its string representation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `list.__str__ is object.__str__` returns `True`, and `object.__str__` is basically implemented like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return repr(self)
```

Unless a type implements its own `__str__`, it uses `object.__str__`.

Most builtin types in Python do not implement their own `__str__`, because they do not have a logical choice for a human-friendly string representation, `list` is no different.

Comment: OK. But if `__str__` is supposed to return a human readable representation and `__repr__` is not, then this implementation breaks the behavior.

Comment: [It is described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). There's not always a clear suitable human-readable representation of an object, so instead of raising an exception they decided to use its `repr` as a "best effort" representation.

Comment: I'm not sure if the human readability is really in the specification of this method, but if so, this is not a correct answer. You cannot break the specification, just because you don't want to raise an exception.

Comment: I don't really know what answer you want. This is the design decision made by the authors of Python, I don't know their exact reasoning, but they describe the behaviour they chose in the documentation.

Comment: The @jasonharper's answer is OK.